# Error using JsUnit with Hudson

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, continuous-integration, hudson, jsunit

I've just started using the JsUnit plugin with Hudson.  The JsUnit tests are passing, but when the JsUnit plugin runs against the test output it's creating this error:

*[xUnit] [ERROR] - Couldn't split JUnit testsuites for the file 'tests/jsunit/logs/JSTEST-1266764410175-0.xml' into JUnit files with one testsuite.*

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix this.  Here's what the output file looks like:

http://www.pastebin.com/m175b27e0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the tip Dave.  I ended up borrowing the XSLT from the JsUnit plugin and creating a python script that applies the transformation and manually fixes the problem in the transformed XML.  Then I added a build step at the end that runs the script on all the files that were generated by JsUnit, bypassing the JsUnit plugin entirely.

A little hacky, but it got the job done.  Here's the code for anybody if they are interested.

http://pastebin.com/3FP6kbLx

Answer (score 2):

[This Hudson bug report](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4829?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel) might help. At least it shows the format expected by the xUnit plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin now for JsUnit integration. It appears you are using JUnit to run your JSUnit tests. They are two different things.

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/JSUnit+plugin